# How to modify the instance attribute rather than the class attribute in Python

Tags: python, class, instance

I want to change the attribute of the instance of T, but when I call update_command_list function of t1, all the attributes of the instances of this class are changed.

If I want to only change the attribute of the instance, how should I change my code?

```
class T():
    def __init__(self, command_list=['a', 'b', 'c']):
        self.command_list = command_list

    def update_command_list(self):
        self.command_list.append('d')

L = []
t1 = T()
t2 = T()
L.append(t1)
L.append(t2)
L[0].update_command_list()
print(L[0].command_list)
print(L[1].command_list)
```

The output is 
    ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']
    ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']

What I want is
    ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']
    ['a', 'b', 'c']

Comment: change `self.command_list = command_list` to `self.command_list = command_list[:]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to change your `__init__()` to remove the default argument. Something like:

```
def __init__(self):
    self.command_list = ['a', 'b', 'c']
```

Then read the following SO question to understand how default arguments work in python: ["Least Astonishment" and the Mutable Default Argument](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1132941/least-astonishment-and-the-mutable-default-argument)